# image inside columns inside block in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, columns

I try to put an image in `columns` environment inside a `block` environment in `beamer`.

Somehow my image is shifting outside the block.

Here's an example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Problem}
\begin{block}{look at that}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \rule{.3\textwidth}{.3\textwidth}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
    Nothing of great importance
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I tried an ugly hack with a `flushright` environment around the image, however then the image is shifting downwards which only looks slightly better.

(How) can this be solved?

Comment: Inside column or block, `\textwidth` is not `\linewidth`!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Problem}
\begin{block}{look at that}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.3\linewidth}
    \rule{\columnwidth}{\columnwidth}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\linewidth}
    Nothing of great importance
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution (thank you [@lumbric](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8964/lumbric?tab=questions)) without columns:
The advantage of this solution is, that you can use 100 % of `linewidth`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Problem}
\begin{block}{look at that}
    \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}%
    \rule{\linewidth}{\linewidth}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}%
    Nothing of great importance%
    \end{minipage}%
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```